# Retrieve specific frame from video | Opencv VideoCapture | C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I have a program that extracts every n-th frame of a video. The current way of doing it is to iterate trough the entire video and when we get to a desired frame we extract it a process it. But this is slow as we are going trough every frame when if we could just jump to the ones we desire it would be much faster. I have searched for solutions but I couldn't find one.

current slow code

```cpp
while (true) {
cv::Mat frame;
vid >> frame;

if (frame.empty()) {
    break;
}

//check if we need the frame
//process frame

}
```

Also tried other versions using stuff like vid.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frame_num)
but that also just seems to do the same thing like the code above but sets back the current frame to the original one so its even slower.

Comment: please read up on how video works. specifically, a "group of frames", and how "seeking" works, and what frames you can jump to directly, and what frames can only be decoded after their predecessors have been. -- best you can do is to use `grab()` and `retrieve()` instead of the compound `read()` method.

Comment: thanks, then I'll see if those can help speed it up at least a little.

Comment: how big is N? for large N, larger than a GOP, seeking is optimal. for smaller N, there's no way in principle to skip decoding intermediate frames because following frames rely on that data. if you had a purely intra-coded video, essentially GOPs of size 1, seeking would be optimal.